# Rancher Keycloak authentication setup

Tags: keycloak, rancher

I'm trying to setup Rancher to use Keycloak as an authentication provider and following the setups laid out [here](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/admin-settings/authentication/keycloak/). The last step says to export the metadata in the `SAML Metadata IDPSSODescriptor` format but I only see `SAML Metadata SPSSODescriptor` as an option. I've tried using that but authentication isn't working - it opens another window with the same Keycloak setup page when clicking the *Authenticate with Keycloak* button to validate the setup. There are no errors in the Docker logs for either the Rancher or Keycloak containers when running `docker logs CONTAINER` command.

I'm wondering if I need to do something specific to setup Keycloak as an IDP to get the correct metadata option but I can't find anything in their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Keycloak 6.0 and up, along with the location of the `IDPSSODescriptor` even its format has changed. [This doc](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/admin-settings/authentication/keycloak/#keycloak-6-0-0-idpssodescriptor-missing-from-options) explains how that can be edited to be used by Rancher

Answer (score -1):

> From the Installation tab, choose the SAML Metadata IDPSSODescriptor format option and download your file.

[image]

Or you can directly visit Keycloak URL with `IDPSSODescriptor` metadata:

```
https://<keycloak-domain>/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/saml/descriptor
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I don't have an option for `IDPSSODescriptor`. I only have `SPSSODescriptor` as an available option.

Comment: I mentioned URL, where you can download it. Did you try it?

Comment: Sorry, been traveling and just got a chance to try the URL. The URL exists but when I try to use that XML from the URL I get a `TestAndEnable Error
SAML: cannot initialize saml SP, cannot decode IDP Metadata content from the config` error.

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/22052) and it mentioned issues in Keycloak 6.0 so I downgraded and it's now working.